# How to filter the result in elastic search to the documents which id contains any of the elements in [10,23,34,44]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am new to elastic search. I am using the following library to help me with building my search query.
Here is the library:

https://github.com/sudo-suhas/elastic-builder

I have the below code to create my queries:

```
        requestBody = elasticSearchBuilder.requestBodySearch()
        .query(
            elasticSearchBuilder.boolQuery()
                .must(elasticSearchBuilder.multiMatchQuery(feilds, searchQuery)
                    .type(sortAlgorithm)
                    .tieBreaker(tieBreaker)
                    .minimumShouldMatch(searchAccuracy))
```

which results in:

```
{
"bool": {
    "must": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "fields": ["name", "owner", "byline_name", "head"],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "tie_breaker": 0.3
        }
    }
}
```

}
   }

Now I want to add another filter in which searches among the documents where the id in in this array: [10,23,34,44]. so I am looking for sth like between or contains or ... whatever can solve this. Can anyone helps me with this?

Update:

```
[
{
"id": "80092",
"categoryId": "43229",
"channelId": "54322",
"channelName": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"owner": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"ownerChannel": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"bylineName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"bylinePublication": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for identifiers, there is a special query called [ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html)

```
POST http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search
Content-type: application/json

{
   "query": {
       "ids" : {
           "values" : ["10", "23", "34", "44"]
       }
   }
}
```

For other fields you can use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query.

```
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "otherField" : [10, 23, 34, 44]}
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks by identifier you mean index? so if I have [10,23,34,44] which all of and  they are not the index should I use terms?

Comment: I mean special field _id https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-id-field.html

Comment: Oh no they are not indexed. Lets say they are ids of my field called product_id then how can I use them with terms?

Comment: You should check the output of your previous query. If it has for instance _id: "44" then this ids query will be valid. Otherwise you should try with terms (modified my answer with example)

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it but a quick question : trems only works with string or it will work with numberts as well?

Comment: So here is my query and though it exists nothing is returned: {"query":{"bool":{"must":{"multi_match":{"query":"hamed minaee","fields":["channel_name","owner","owner_channel","byline_name","byline_publication","headline","seo_terms","category","body","pull_quote"],"type":"best_fields","tie_breaker":0.3}},"filter":[{"range":{"create_datetime_milisec":{"gt":"1421893256000"}}},{"range":{"create_datetime_milisec":{"lt":"1611893256000"}}},{"terms":{"channel_id":[44322,22]}}]}}};

Comment: if I remove this: terms":{"channel_i‌​d":[44322,22] the result will return

Comment: Yes, terms should be working for numbers as well. Could you modify your question and add one document from your index that you want to be matched by your query ?

Comment: I added the document

Comment: @HamedMinaee, just to clarify. If you have numbers in your JSON, you should have numbers in your query (like in my answer), if you have strings (like you've posted) you should also use the same query but with strings like : "terms" : { "channelId" : ["54322", "0", "1", "2"]}.